# What is the return type of "return" C#

Tags: c#, console, return, return-type

I am making a console application and I have a "Menu" where the user can enter information to create a new Person object. The following is inside a method.

```
        Write("Please enter the first name: ", false);
        string fName = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        Write("Please enter the middle initial: ", false);
        string mInitial = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        Write("Please enter the last name: ", false);
        string lName = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
```

like so. I want the user to be able to exit the method at anytime if they decide they don't want to be making a new person. So I'd like to make a new method called "CheckExit" and if they type "EXIT" it will leave the "CreatePerson" method. So I want the "CheckExit" to return a return. Otherwise I have to add an "if" statement after every input and that gets clutter-y.

Is this possible? Does return have a return type? What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: On that note I don't even know if a return from inside an if would work of just exit the if statement. I might have to use a goto. Eitherway that's besides the point

Comment: But you want to end the program or to end making the new person routine?

Comment: End making a new person routine. Basically just go up a menu lvl. But I don't want to have to do this after every entry.
if(fname == "EXIT")
{
    Console.Write("Do you really want to leave this menu?");
    Console.ReadLine();
    return;
}

Comment: You can `throw exception` in the method and `return` in the corresponding `catch`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`return` is not a type that you can return, it's a keyword for returning a result. So unfortunately what you are trying to do is not possible.
However, you can make your code much more readable and extendable by using an array of queries and getting the results for each inside of a loop. This has the bonus effect of being able to add more queries with ease.

```cs
// you can put these queries somewhere outside the function
string[] queries = {"Please enter the first name: ", ...}
var results = new List<string>();

foreach (string query in queries) {
    Write(query, false);
    var result = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    if (result.Equals("EXIT") {
        return;
    }
    results.Add(result);
}

// handle your inputs from the results list here ...
```

Comment: This is not more readable.

Comment: This looks like Javascript, not C#.

Comment: @outflak Microsoft C# uses the Allman style, but Mono C# also use the Java style used by JavaScript.

Comment: @user253751 How so? Like ternary expressions, it's quite readable if you're highly literate. But there's a case to be made for making things readable to the less literate.

Comment: @user560822 It is not as simple as possible. And your description of people who think it is less readable as "less literate" is an attempt to make yourself feel better about your preference of writing code that is as complex as possible. It also makes you feel smarter than other people.

Comment: @user253751 You couldn't be more wrong. The code in this answer is *much* simpler than the OP's code, for the reason the answerer correctly explained. And I'm a strong advocate of readability and maintainability as the first concern after correctness.

Comment: @user560822 the OP's code has lower cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: @user253751 An [extremely dubious metric](https://www.cs.du.edu/~snarayan/sada/teaching/COMP3705/lecture/p1/cycl-1.pdf) that fell out of use decades ago, and for good reason.

Comment: @user253751 if you want it to be more readable, you can easily accomplish this by extracting the `foreach` loop into a separate function. But the point if this answer is to make the code maintainable. It doesn't matter how many queries you have, all the logic in the bottom lines stays the same.

Answer (score 7):

You could create a method to read from console to automate this process, something like

```
internal class StopCreatingPersonException : Exception
{}

public static string ReadFromConsole(string prompt)
{
     Write(prompt, false);
     var v = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
     if (v == "EXIT") { throw new StopCreatingPerson (); }
     return v;
}
```

Then your code would look like:

```
try {
    string fName = ReadFromConsole("Please enter the first name: ");
    ....
}
catch (StopCreatingPersonException)
{ }
```

Comment: Interesting I was unaware of creating my own exceptions. I will learn more about this thank you.

Comment: @CaiusJard done! Thanks for noting, it's a good practice.

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, it would be better, I'll edit. Thanks

Comment: @Arkyris it doesn't specifically have to be your own exception; this technique would work well even just by saying `throw new Exception()` and catching it. There is also a OperationCanceledException in the framework whose name perhaps fits what you're trying to do and could make sense to use. Typically we throw different Exception types so we can differentiate in catching some and not others, but in essence the only way for a sub method to make an outer method return is for the sub method to throw, the outer to not catch and then control returns to the method above the outer/a "return return"

Comment: @Arkyris By the way if you want to stop creating person but still have the part completed Person object to return, you'll need to declare the Person object outside the try so it's available as a reference in the catch handler.

Comment: @dgg [Don't use exceptions for flow control](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why) and [don't create exception classes unless it's really necessary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions#use-the-predefined-net-exception-types). On the other hand, I've seen even worse; I'm maintaining code where a supposedly senior developer controlled program flow with stringly typed exceptions distinguished by their error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Return statements are used to return a value from a method that has a return type. When you write a method with void as the return type, you can use the `return;` to exit the method.

e.g, following method uses a string as the return type,

```
public string ReturnString() { return "thisString"; }
```

If you are writing a method that creates the object and returns it to the calling method, then the return type would be the Person (unless you intend do something else). If you check the user input and decide not to create a Person, you can use `return null;`.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Initial { get; set; }
}

public static Person CreatePerson()
{
    Person person = new Person();
    Console.Write("Please enter the first name: ", false);
    string fName = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fName) || fName.ToLower().Equals("exit"))
        return null;
    person.FirstName = fName;

    Console.Write("Please enter the middle initial: ", false);
    string mInitial = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mInitial) || mInitial.ToLower().Equals("exit"))
        return null;
    person.Initial = mInitial;

    Console.Write("Please enter the last name: ", false);
    string lName = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lName) || lName.ToLower().Equals("exit"))
        return null;
    person.LastName = lName;

    return person;
}
```

And you can use this method in the Main,

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    Person person = CreatePerson();
    if (person == null) {
       Console.WriteLine("User Exited.");
    }
    else
    {
       // Do Something with person.
    }
}
```

Comment: They would still have to take the time to enter everything, wouldn't they?

Comment: if they type in exit at any time, it would stop. return means, leave the method, `CreatePerson` right away.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to use `return` if you want to terminate method. But you can shorten your code some thing like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        createPerson();

        Console.WriteLine("Some display goes here...");
    }

    static void createPerson()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first name: ");
        string fName = getInput();
        if (isExit(fName))
        {
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the middle initial: ");
        string mInitial = getInput();
        if (isExit(mInitial))
        {
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the last name: ");
        string lName = getInput();
        if (isExit(lName))
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    static string getInput()
    {
        return Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    }

    static bool isExit(string value)
    {
        if (value == "EXIT")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Create person has been canceled by the user.");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```